# Published MVC Application to Azure, but HTML is not displaying correctly

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I published my MVC application to azure hosting web application. When I run the MVC application in debug locally, the page loads and all the HTML is displayed. As soon as I run it on the Azure host, the page loads but only the navbar and background are shown, but not the actual content. When I view the source the HTML is all there but it is not visible. Is there any reason this would occur?

Comment: Diff the two html sources and see what the change is

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when you're ***not*** deploying the css file. Create a new MVC app and deploy to Azure - it should work correctly. Now compare to your project.